# Formulario de Registro y login con JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, login, validación

Tengo la necesidad de crear un formulario de registro y login con js sin utilizar php, ejemplo cuando este en registro estos datos sean guardados en vectores, y en el logueo poder confirmar que estos se encuentran dentro del vector y asi dirigirme a la pagina principal ya creada.
Y en tal caso que pongan alguna de la informacion correcta en el login y otra mal, o no se encuentre dentro de la informacion registrada los mande a registrarse o a revisar la informacion ofrecida.
Repito, no puedo usar php, es para una tarea.
Gracias por su tiempo.

```
    <div class="formulario">
        <h2> Registrate </h2>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario"  id="user" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombres"  id="name" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" id="lname" required >
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="pass" required >
            <button onclick="registro()">Registrarse</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</br>
        <div class="formulario">
            <h2> Login </h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" id="userlogin" required>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="passlogin" required>
                <button onclick="login()" id="botonlog">Iniciar Sesion</button>
           </form>
        </div>
        <div class="reset-password">
            <a href="#">Olvide mi contraseña</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo que tengo HTML, el punto es que tengo que almacenar todo dentro de vectores y matrices. No puedo usar base de datos.

Comment: y que llevas hecho ya ?

Comment: javascript también se pude usar del lado del servidor: https://nodejs.org/es/

Answer (score 2):

¿No puedes almacenarlo desde el LocalStorage?
https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36 Aquí lo explican muy bien; saludos!